# Which Command? A paragraph, first word bold, not listed in table of contents

Tags: macros

i couldnt find this on web search, my prof. told me to use a "paragraph" command, with attributes like in the headline description, in certain situations. But all I could find is a command called "paragraph", it lists itself in the table of contents though, which I want to avoid. Which command am I looking for to get what I need.

I use this document class

```
\documentclass[ngerman,bt]{dbvdoc}
```

thanks a lot in advance,
daniel

Comment: It is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: ok, I will do it later, I thought maybe some people know the answer without testing it.

Comment: The problem is that this **much depends** on the class you use, I posted likely-working answer below.

Comment: If the `dbvdoc` class is based on `KOMA-Script` – what we can’t see, because it seems, it is an internal document class (for the German insurance DBV?) – then there is a command `\minisec` which works as expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Play with both counters of the minimal example,  or use  paragraph*, or use the description environment if do you want also a hanging indent

```
\documentclass{article}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents{}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\paragraph{paragraph } numbered but not listed in TOC.
\paragraph*{Paragraph } not numbered and not listed.
\begin{description}
\item [{description}] environment
\item [{second}] item of descrition
\end{description}
\end{document
\end{document}
```

Comment: the \paragraph with the asterisk did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

`\paragraph` is a sectioning command whose numbering and inclusion in the table of contents is governed by the counters `secnumdepth` and `tocdepth`.

Specifically (in the standard classes) it is considered at level 4:

> chapter = 0 (if existent in the class)
>   section = 1
>   subsection = 2
>   subsubsection = 3
>   paragraph = 4
>   subparagraph = 5

Thus any setting such as `\setcounter{tocdepth}{<n>}` (where `<n>` is an integer less than 4) will *not* include sections introduced by `\paragraph` in the table of contents. The default value of `tocdepth` is 2.

However, sections introduced with `\paragraph*` will *not* be numbered nor included in the table of contents.

I recommend you not using `\paragraph*` directly, though: write in your preamble something like

```
\newcommand{\mydivision}[1]{\paragraph*{#1}}
```

and use `\mydivision{Word}`. You may so easily change your mind about the rendering of these things. For example, a definition that doesn't abuse the sectioning commands might be

```
\newcommand{\mydivision}[1]{%
  \par\addvspace{\baselineskip}
  \noindent\textbf{#1}\enspace\ignorespaces}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to include these two lines in your preamble. They modify the depth of table of contents:

```
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
```

Comment: hmm thank you it doesnt work. Im on depth level 2, later I will go deeper. The reason I dont want to have it in the table of contents is because the section is too short.